# What is Object(0) in jQuery proto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype-chain

[image: Object(0)]

What does Object(0) stand for and why is it an Array instead of Object?

Comment: It's `$.fn` (or `$.prototype`) and has a `.length` property, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your result I assume you are using a **JQUERY CALL**, *for example $("input")*, that returns an Array-Like object.

To understand what `_proto_` is, you need to understand `prototypical inheritance`.[MDN Explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

In essence the `root` object you are inheriting from is an array, and that is because you are accessing an array-like return type.[explanation on why it is an array and not an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) *almost at the bottom of the page.*

*from the second mdn link*

> The **proto** getter function exposes the value of the internal
>   [[Prototype]] of an object. For objects created using an object
>   literal, this value is Object.prototype. For objects created using
>   array literals, this value is Array.prototype. For functions, this
>   value is Function.prototype. For objects created using new fun, where
>   fun is one of the built-in constructor functions provided by
>   JavaScript (Array, Boolean, Date, Number, Object, String, and so on —

Comment: jquery does not return an array.

Comment: The call he is making probably does, i will bold the word call to emphasis that

Comment: All I did was console.log($('div')) and the result I got was what is shown in the picture.

Comment: Bingo, that will return an array of objects, like my answer states

Comment: @gh9: No; it returns an _array-like_ object.

Comment: @SLaks  fair enough, I have modified my answer

Answer (score 1):

jQuery returns an array-like object. I'm guessing it's `Object(0)` because it's based on a regular JavaScript `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still curious about `Object(0)` or [array-like] object

- The `Object(0)` appears because `prototype.length` is `0`
- The Array-like appears because `prototype.splice` is there

[simple example of the phenomenon of Object(0) in proto](https://github.com/dugi-x/array-like-selector)

Comment: Several questions: 1) What sence in `prototype.length = 0`? 2) Why does adding `splice` make an object array-like? I can't do this for usual objects (without a constructor). 3) Is this possible?